# How to highlight areas in an imagemap on hover in a partial html file with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have set up a single page web app using AngularJS and in one of my partials I have an imagemap and would like to highlight the areas on mouseover. Ive tried searching around trying to figure out how to do this and I am not sure what is going wrong. Here is the code.

I tried using https://github.com/cowglow/AngularJS-maphilights as a resource

```
<section class="artistinfo">
 <div class="artist cf">
<h1>Select a room for more details</h1>
<div class="info">
  <img ng-src="images/housediagram.jpg" alt="Photo of thing" class="map" usemap="#houseMap">
  <map name="houseMap" id="Map" class="maphilight">
    <area name="kitchen" shape="poly" coords="197,193,348,194,349,301,197,302" href="#/kitchen"/>
    <area name="livingroom" shape="poly" coords="349,194,349,300,562,301,561,192" href="#/livingroom"/>
    <area name="laundry" shape="poly" coords="389,309,390,399,562,399,563,308" href="#/laundry"/>
    <area name="basement" shape="poly" coords="387,309,388,399,197,399,197,306" href="#/basement"/>
    <area name="office" shape="poly" coords="198,108,196,190,301,191,301,83,256,80" href="#/office"/>
    <area name="bathroom" shape="poly" coords="301,83,302,190,418,191,417,83" href="#/bathroom"/>
    <area name="bedroom" shape="poly" coords="419,83,417,192,560,191,560,109,494,80" href="#/bedroom"/>
  </map>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-maphilights.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    angular.module('map', ['maphilights']);

  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console

Comment: @shushanthp nope no errors

Comment: could you please create jsfiddle or anything to see

Comment: In case you can't find the project, you can find it here
https://github.com/cowglow/AngularJS-rwdImageMaps

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to edit his code since he doesn't actually invoke the jQuery function that does the highlighting. You can replace the link function with the following

```
link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            $(element).load(function () {
                $(element).maphilight();
            }).trigger('load');
        }
```

Also, be sure to apply your directive on the `<img>` tag, not the `<map>` tag.